# Html entity &quot; is replaced with actual double quote while using document.body.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, html-entities

In my case, server sends following html response

`{"Testlink":"&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;"}`

This response is set to body.

When I read this response using document.body.innertHTML, I get following string in javascript

`{"Testlink":"&lt;a href="http://www.google.com"&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;"}`

In this string, `&quot;` is replaced with actual double quote character. This does not happen with other entities like `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

This behavior is consistent across FF, IE and Chrome.

Is this expected behavior or an issue? If issue, how can this be solved/fixed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing `&quot;` with `&amp;quot;`

Comment: `&amp;quot;` somewhat solved the problem. Now following string is read in javascript `{"Testlink":"&lt;a href=&amp;quot;http://www.google.com&amp;quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;"}`. In this case, special handling is required to convert from `&amp;quot;` to double quote. Still wondering why different treatment for `&quot;` in innerHtml?